# $1+x+\ldots+x^n$ perfect square

Tags: number-theory

Let $p$ be the polynomial $p(x)=1+x+\ldots+x^n$.
For which couples $(a, n)\in\mathbb{N}^2$, $p(a)$ is a perfect square? I'm particularly interested in $p(3)$.

Comment: $p(x)=\displaystyle\frac{x^{n+1}-1}{x-1}$

Comment: I know, but what can we do with that?

Comment: If $a=3$,then $n=0,1,4$ are all the solutions.

Comment: @Sophie Can you show us the proof?

Comment: An idea: over the splitting field $K$ of $1 + x + ... + x^n$, the Galois group permutes the ideals $(a - \zeta^j)\mathcal{O}_K$, it also permutes prime factors of an ideal $p\mathcal{O}_K$ for a rational prime $p$.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The Diophantine equation $f_n(x)=1+x+x^2+\cdots+x^{n-1}=y^2$.

Ribenboim's book on Catalan's conjecture has a detailed 
analysis of this Diophantine equation. Except the cases noted below, there are no more non-trivial solutions.
Here are some of the easy cases:

1. There are always the two trivial solutions  $x=0$ and $x=-1$.
2. If $n$ is a square, then $x=1$ is a third solution.
3. For $n=3$, if $x\not=0$, then $-2|x|<x<2|x|$ implies
   $(|x|-1)^2<1+x+x^2<(|x|+1)^2$ so $f_3(x)$ can only be the square  $x^2$.
   This gives the other trivial solution $x=-1$.
4. For $n=4$,  look at Monthly problem 11203 (Feb. 2006) or Exercise 1.10
   in Edward's book *Fermat's Last Theorem*. The only solutions are  $x=-1,0,1,7$.
5. For $n=5$,  see Ed Burger's book *Exploring The Number Jungle* (Exercise 12.11). By comparing $4f_5(x)$
   with $(2x^2+x)^2$ and $(2x^2+x+1)^2$, we find that the only solutions are  $x=-1,0,3$.
6. For $n=6$, we factor $f_6(x)=f_2(x^3)f_3(x)$.
   By the formula $2=f_2(x^3)-(x-1)f_3(x)$ we see that
   $\gcd(f_2(x^3),f_3(x))$ divides 2. But $f_3(x)$ is always odd, so the gcd equals 1.
   This forces $f_3(x)$ to be a square so we end up with the trivial solutions $x=0,-1$.
7. For $n=7$, if $x>5$ we have
   $$(16x^3+8x^2+6x+5)^2< 256 f_7(x)< (16x^3+8x^2+6x+6)^2,$$
   while
   for $x<-4$ we get  $$(16x^3+8x^2+6x+5)^2< 256 f_7(x)< (16x^3+8x^2+6x+4)^2.$$
   Check the values between and you find that there are only trivial solutions.

By this stage, elementary methods get tougher to push through.

Comment: Can you please give me the exact title of Ribenboim's book? Thanks!

Comment: @user72870 Catalan's Conjecture: Are 8 and 9 the Only Consecutive Powers?

Answer (score 6):

If $a=3$,then $n=0,1,4$ are all the solutions.

$p(3)=1+3+…+3^n=\frac{3^{n+1}-1}{3-1}=y^2,3^{n+1}-1=2y^2$

Denote $m=n+1,t=\sqrt{-2}$, then $$3^m=1+2y^2$$
$$(1+yt)(1-yt)=(1+t)^m(1-t)^m$$
We get $$1+yt=±(1+t)^m,1-yt=±(1-t)^m$$
so $$1=±\frac{(1+t)^m+(1-t)^m}{2},y=±\frac{(1+t)^m-(1-t)^m}{2t}$$
We get $m=1,2,5$, and $|y|=1,2,11$.

Comment: do you have a proof that there is no solution for $m>5$ ?

Comment: @mercio,yeah,I will edit it to make it complete.

Comment: @mercio,well,I find this is not easy..

Answer (score 0):

There're lots of pairs: 
$$\,p(1,n^2)\,,\,\,\forall\,n\in\Bbb N\;,$$

$$\,p(3,1)=2^2\;,\;p(3,4)=11^2\;,\ldots$$

Comment: Shouldn't be $p(1,n^2-1)$?