# The real part of $z^n$

Tags: complex-analysis, diophantine-approximation

Prove that $${\displaystyle\lim \limits_{n \to +\infty}{|r^ncos(nθ)|}}=+\infty,$$

where  $n$ is integer, $r>1$, $θ/π$ is irrational.

I got this problem from here [$1+x+\ldots+x^n$ perfect square](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/372367/1x-ldotsxn-perfect-square/372387#372387) , I think it's true for the general situation.

PS:
The original problem is to prove 
$${\displaystyle\lim \limits_{n \to +\infty}{|z^n+\overline{z}^n|}}=+\infty,$$
where $n$ is integer, $z=x+yi,\overline{z}=x-yi,x>y>0,x^2+y^2>1,i=\sqrt{-1}.$

But according to the answer given by @mrf, this is not true when $y/x=tan(π/8)$,so I add the condition that $θ/π$ is irrational.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is this homework ?

Comment: @Kasper,no,this is not homework

Comment: Is $n\in\mathbb Z$? @sophia

Comment: @Babak S.yes,n is always an integer.

Comment: @Kasper: She is just asking for any help of us. :-) We are not forced to answer her in a complete detailed answer. So let's help her. +1

Comment: @BabakS. I didn't downvote, but I think it is good that the OP knows why there are downvotes, and that some people here will consider to close this question. Go ahead helping here !

Comment: @Kasper: Exactly! :-)

Comment: @Kasper,thanks for your advice,I have been here for more than a month now,I know how to work here,I didn't write anything just because I have no idea to this problem.I have try many numerical calculate but it's not worth to write here, maybe my mistake is I forget to add the link for this problem.

Comment: Since it has been edited, the only given answer doesn't match the question anymore!

Comment: @girianshiido,it's my fault.@mrf's answer is helpful to me,but my main question was not answered,so I have to edit it to make the question meaningful.

Comment: Maybe you should try to reverse back to the original question and complete it instead!

Comment: @girianshiido,I will take your suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The statement can be false even when you assume $\frac{\theta}{\pi}$ is irrational.

Let $(s_k)_{k=1,2\ldots}$ be the sequence defined recursively by:

$$s_k = \begin{cases}1,&\quad\text{ for }k = 1\\2^{s_{k-1}},&\quad\text{ for }k > 1\end{cases}$$

and $s$ be the Liouville number $s = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} 2^{-s_k}$.
For $r = \sqrt{2}$, and $\theta = s\frac{\pi}{2}$, we have:

$$\begin{align}r^{2^{s_m}} |\cos( 2^{s_m} \theta )| = & 
2^{(2^{s_m}/2)} \left|\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2}(1 + \sum_{k=m+1}^{\infty} 2^{s_m-s_{k}})\right)\right|\\ \sim & \frac{\pi}{2}2^{(2^{s_m}/2) + s_m - s_{m+1}}\\
= & \frac{\pi}{2}2^{s_m - (s_{m+1}/2)}
\end{align}$$

As this converges to $0$ as $m \to \infty$, $r^{n} |\cos(n\theta)|$ has a
sub-sequence which converges to $0$ and hence it cannot diverges to $\infty$.

Comment: Thank you,it seems that my idea is completely wrong..Maybe it's true for irrational algebraic numbers :)

Comment: @Sophie The statement is probably true when $z$ is an algebraic number and $\frac{\theta}{\pi}$ is irrational. I have an argument for this in an [old post](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/sci.math/XCljh7L4E0U/90q942YOjw4J) on sci.math. However, it is an argument not a proof because I don't really know the Baker and Wustholz theory of linear form used in my argument there.

Answer (score 2):

Use the polar representation of $z$, $z = re^{i\theta}$. By the assumptions, $r > 1$ and $0 < \theta < \pi/4$.

Computing, you get $z^n = r^n e^{in\theta}$ and $\bar z^n = r^n e^{-in\theta}$, so
$$ z^n + \bar z^n = r^n \big( e^{in\theta} + e^{-in\theta} \big) = 2 r^n \cos(n\theta).$$

Here you can see that there's something wrong with your (supposed) conclusion. Take for example $z = 2e^{i\pi/8}$, then $z^n + \bar z^n = 0$ if $n = 8k+4$ for $k\in\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: +1.nice,how about if $θ/π$ is irrational?For example,$z=1+\sqrt{2}i$,this is the original problem in that link.