# Prove that $\sum\limits_{i=0}^{k} p^{2i}$ ($p$ is prime) is never a perfect square

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, summation

Prove that
$$
\sum_{i=0}^{k} p^{2i}
$$
where $k > 0$ and $p$ is an arbitrary prime, is never a perfect square. I think you can prove it by letting $q = \sum\limits_{i=0}^k a_ip^i$, then expanding $q^2$ and equaling coefficients of $p^l$ in $q^2$ and the original sum, thus showing no such $a_i$ in $q$ exist. But I'm kinda looking for a more elegant solution. Thanks.

Comment: That looks like a [geometric series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series) to me...

Comment: It is. Its sum is $\frac{p^{2(k+1)}-1}{p^2-1}$. But it doesn't really help me, I'm a newbie at number theory.

Comment: Try factoring the numerator.

Comment: If $k=0$ it is a perfect square so perhaps let $i=1$???

Comment: Let's call it a trivial case and disregard it completely. :)

Comment: Ok I agree, and I'll do that.

Comment: I've shown that if $p$ is an odd prime $k \equiv 0,-1 \pmod4$, in fact if k is odd it is $\equiv 3 \pmod 8$, but I can't get any further.

Comment: This is related to http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/372367/1x-ldotsxn-perfect-square ,where $x=p^2$

Comment: @Sophie; in fact, one of the answers to that question answers this as well.

Comment: @Hecke I'm sure the primality of $p$ will allow easier methods here.

Answer (score 2):

My partial process:

Assume $x^2=\sum_{i=0}^{k} p^{2i}$. Working modulo $p$ gives $x^2\equiv 1\pmod p$ or:
$$x\equiv\pm1 \pmod p.$$
Using the formula for power series gives: $x^2=\frac{p^{2(k+1)}-1}{p^2-1}$, or:
$$x^2p^2-x^2=p^{2(k+1)}-1\\
(xp)^2+1^2=(p^{k+1})^2+x^2$$
This is in the form  $x^2+y^2=z^2+w^2$, which as discussed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/153603/diophantine-equation-a2b2-c2d2), is of the form:
$$(xp,1,p^{k+1},x) = (a c + b d , b c - a d , a c - b d , a d + b c),$$
Which lead to some complex identities between $a$, $b$, $c$ and $d$. For example, $bc-ad=1$ implies $(a,b)=(a,c)=(b,d)=(c,d)=1$.