# Sum of a Sequence of Prime Powers $p^{2n}+p^{2n-1}+\cdots+p+1$ is a Perfect Square

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, square-numbers

Find all primes p such that $p^{2n}+p^{2n-1}+p^{2n-2}+\cdots+p^{2}+p+1$ is a square for some value of n.

Comment: I've tried to simplify the condition about and use algebraic manipulations, as well as some basic number theoretic tests. I have made little progress for around an hour.

Comment: $p=3, n=2$ gives $121=11^2$

Comment: $n=1$ never works, because $p^2 < 1+p+p^2 < (p+1)^2$

Comment: $
p^{2n + 1}  - 1 = \left( {p - 1} \right)\left( {{\rm 1 + }p{\rm  + }p^{\rm 2}  +  \cdots  + p^{2n} } \right)
$

Comment: Similar: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/372367 and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/379731

Comment: What do you mean by 'all primes'? Are you sure there are only a finite number of answers that satisfy the condition?

Comment: I threw Mathematica at this.  Up to $n = 100$ for the first 200 primes (so up to 1223), this is true only for the $p = 3, n = 2$ case that Marco mentioned.

Answer (score 3):

Some partial results. 
First we show that $p\geq3$ for any $n\geq1$. Assume otherwise i.e. that $p=2$ then
$$2^{2n}+2^{2n-1}+...+2+1=x^2\Rightarrow 2^{2n+1}-1=x^2\Rightarrow 2^{2n+1}=x^2+1$$
Since $n\geq1$ then 
$$2^{2n+1}\equiv0\mod{4}\Rightarrow x^2\equiv3\mod{4}$$
which is impossible as a square is either $1$ or $0$ modulo $4$. So $p$ is an odd prime and clearly $x$ is an odd number as well.
Now let $p>2$ and $p\equiv1\mod{4}$ then
$$p^{2n}+p^{2n-1}+...+p^2+p+1\equiv2n+1\equiv x^2\mod{4}$$
Since $x$ is odd then $$2n+1\equiv1\mod{4}\Rightarrow n\equiv0\mod{2}$$
When $p\equiv-1\mod{4}$ does not reveal any extra information as 
$$p^{2n}+p^{2n-1}+...+p^2+p+1\equiv1\equiv x^2\mod{4}$$

Comment: Thanks. I have made a a few of these observations, and some in the related threads linked above. But I don't have sufficient evidence to complete the solution. Please let us know when you have got it.