# Are $121$ and $400$ the only perfect squares of the form $\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n}p^k$?

Tags: number-theory, square-numbers

I've been looking for perfect squares that can be represented as $\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n}p^k$.

Of course, both $n$ and $p$ should be natural numbers larger than $1$.

---

Searching up to $n=100$ and $p=200$, I found only $2$ cases:

- $121=11^2=3^0+3^1+3^2+3^3+3^4=\sum\limits_{k=0}^{4}3^k$
- $400=20^2=7^0+7^1+7^2+7^3=\sum\limits_{k=0}^{3}7^k$

Is there any way to prove that there are no other cases?

Comment: FWIW, I think these occurrences are rather coincidental and I think you'd be hard pressed to find relevant theory. Also, personally I would say that $121$ and $400$ aren't the only ones since I don't see any heuristic reason why that would be the case.

Comment: $p$ an integer or $p$ a prime?

Comment: @Soke: Thanks. You are possibly correct in both statements, but I don't see a single mathematical reasoning in your comment to support either one of them.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen: An integer (as specified in the question). I realized that it might be confusing, but I kinda ran out of "natural number denoting" letters that were visibly distinguishable from one another.

Comment: @barakmanos I realize, it's just speculation.

Comment: Some of thorniest open problems in number theory come about from this interplay between additive number theory and multiplicative number theory.

Comment: @James47: It reminds me of something I read on some "mathematical novel". I think it was *The Music of Primes* or *Fermat's Last Theorem*... Anyway, it said something like - "Mathematics is like a vast ocean of unknown, with little islands of knowledge and nothing that connects between them"... So if I understand you correctly, those two theories that you've mentioned are two separate islands in that ocean.

Comment: You can rewrite $\sum_{k=0}^n p^k = \frac{p^{k+1}-1}{p-1}$

Comment: see pages 54-57 of Dickson volume 1, https://books.google.com/books?id=FYWn8XWrAI0C&pg=PA54&dq=dickson+fermat+wallis+brouncker&hl=en&sa=X&ei=js_GVIr1OcirogTpy4DYBw&ved=0CCUQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=dickson%20fermat%20wallis%20brouncker&f=false

Comment: Possibly of interest:  http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/aa/aa64/aa6413.pdf

Comment: Definitely of interest:  http://arxiv.org/pdf/1312.4037v1.pdf

Comment: So by Proposition 1 of the last link the answer is yes. Quite surprising.

Comment: I think it's much easier to find primes of this form than squares of this form. In a randomly selected bunch of consecutive integers, the primes are likelier more common than the squares.

Comment: @BarryCipra: Yep, definitely of interest. So these are indeed the only $2$ known solutions, out of $4$ known solutions under a slightly more generalized conjecture (of perfect powers instead of perfect squares)... I assume that I will not get a better answer to my question at this point :)

Comment: Similar, though not _exact_ duplicates: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1098095, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/372367, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/379731

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Turning a comment into an answer (of sorts)....

Various papers (e.g., [this one](http://www.mscand.dk/article/viewFile/15038/13033) by Yann Bugeaud and Preda Mihailescu) cite papers by Nagell and Ljunggren as proving there are no perfect squares of the given form other than the ones the OP found.

As for the more general problem of representing an arbitrary perfect power, a [recent paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1312.4037v1.pdf) by Michael Bennett and Aaron Levin offers this assessment in its abstract (boldface emphasis added):

> The Diophantine equation ${x^n−1\over x-1} = y^q$ has four known
>   solutions in integers $x$, $y$, $q$ and $n$ with $|x|, |y|, q \gt 1$
>   and $n \gt 2$. Whilst we expect that there are, in fact, no more
>   solutions, **such a result is well beyond current technology.**

The other two solutions referred to are the perfect cube $7^3$ expressed as $1+18+18^2$ and $1+(-19)+(-19)^2$.

See also the [MathOverflow answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/58697/a-geometric-series-equalling-a-power-of-an-integer) by quid.

Comment: I thought the article in the link you specified at the comment suggested that the "no perfect squares of the given form" conjecture was still unproved (I must have mistaken it for the more generalized conjecture). Thanks.

Comment: @barakmanos, I initially misread the abstract that way too, until I looked carefully at the article's Proposition 1.  It's a little unclear how simple or difficult the Nagell-Ljunggren proof for your perfect-square case is; I haven't been able to find it online.  (It might be hidden in plain sight in one of the papers; maybe an actual expert can weigh in on the subject.)

Comment: Sounds like you're still not 100% sure that it **has been** proved...

Comment: No, the various papers make it clear there's a proof, they just don't reproduce it (that I can see).  What I really mean is, there might be some fairly simple argument that takes care of the perfect-square case.

Comment: OK, gotcha... And the more generalized (perfect-power) case is yet unproven, right?

Comment: Yes, that's how I read things.  (Shall we delete the last portion of these comments, to remove clutter no one needs to read?)